# No module named 'ffi'

Tags: python, windows-10, gunicorn

I'm trying to run gunicorn server on my windows 10 locally and I'm getting this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffi'.

This is my code

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Server()
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio)

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connect ', sid)
```

I'm running this command
gunicorn --threads 50 main:app

```
  File "C:\Users\Mr Nash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\gunicorn-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('gunicorn==20.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')())
  File "C:\Users\Mr Nash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\gunicorn-script.py", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "C:\Users\Mr Nash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "C:\Users\Mr Nash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Mr Nash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gunicorn-20.1.0-py3.9.egg\gunicorn\app\wsgiapp.py", line 9, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.base import Application
  File "C:\Users\Mr Nash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gunicorn-20.1.0-py3.9.egg\gunicorn\app\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gunicorn import util
  File "C:\Users\Mr Nash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gunicorn-20.1.0-py3.9.egg\gunicorn\util.py", line 8, in <module>
    import fcntl
  File "C:\Users\Mr Nash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\fcntl.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ffi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffi'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install ffi
```

should do the trick